# Quarkus opentracing

Tags: java, logging, quarkus, jaeger, opentracing

Looking to implement open tracing on Quarkus based on the info below:

https://quarkus.io/guides/opentracing

However, it seems to require a separate Jaeger instance for grabbing all the traces across all services. Is it possible to write the trace information to the logs of the current service as well as a separate Jaeger instance?

Comment: As is mentioned in the docs, users are encouraged to use https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry instead of OpenTracing which has been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did switch to using the telemetry. I have added the extension in the build.gradle and added the properties in the application.properties. However, i am getting the following error on startup of my server. Any idea what I am missing: Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.otel.exporter.otlp.traces.endpoint" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

Answer (score 0):

The current recommended way to do tracing in Quarkus is with OpenTelemetry. OpenTracing is deprecated.
See: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-observability-roadmap-2023/

In order to have logs from traces, you can use the OpenTelemetry collector and send the output to the log.
Here is an example of a colector configuration [here](https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/blob/main/docker-compose/basic/otel-collector-config-tofile.yaml).
The important part is on line 45.

Comment: Thank you. i have the open telemetry working with application;properties, build.gradle changes as well as the @WithSpan in the code. However, this is creating a new span for every method with the WithSpan annotation. How can I have the trace/span carried forward for each of the called methods so we can see the time taken for each of them? Also do i need to do anything else in the code for enabling tracing across multiple Quarkus services? I do see the trace separately for each of the services but it's not showing me the trace of flows from one service to the other. the tracingcontext is null